# How to quickly set year only in iOS 7

Tags: ios, settings

Can someone please explain how you can quickly set the YEAR within the date and time settings?

If the battery has been removed then the iPhone is reset back to Jan 1st 1970. This means that the network will not sync and you won't get a signal. Therefore the automatic date setting will not work either.

The only way I have managed so far is to literally scroll through everyday of every month of every year up to the present day until it is correct. This is naturally tiresome and also impractical as often in swiping you drag up the quick menu from the bottom.

Answer (score 12):

Try connecting to iTunes, it automatically syncs to the current date.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's something you need to do repeatedly, if it were just once, you could just deal with it.

*As an Apple-Certified Mac Technician I should advise that unauthorised hardware modifications will permanently exclude the device from the official circuit, meaning that your customers won't be able to benefit from Apple's limited warranty, AppleCare or Out of Warranty service.*

That said, and assuming you are doing something entirely innocent, you should try hooking up your device to a computer. In the absence of a wireless connection (or being unable to connect to your network because of the wrong date), the device's date should sync with that of your computer.

Comment: How is setting the date a hardware modification?

Comment: Well, removing the battery is.

Comment: You don't have to take the battery out to have this problem -- just let it go completely flat.